# Joi validation read another data

Tags: node.js, validation, joi

I have some code to validate id from params, and some data from body

```
const schema = Joi.object({
    id: Joi.string().required(),
    quantity: Joi.number().required().when('ids', {
        is: Joi.exist(),
        then: Joi.forbidden()
    }),
    ids: Joi.alternatives().conditional('quantity', {
        is: Joi.exist(),
        then: Joi.forbidden(),
        otherwise: Joi.array().required()
    })
}).or('quantity', 'ids')
```

when validating, object id read ids object

[image]

and give error return

```
"message": "Invalid value { id: [ 3, 4 ] }",
"stack": "Error: Invalid value { id: [ 3, 4 ] }\n"
```

I just wanna ask, why Id read data from ids?